# 'pip' not showing in command prompt or terminal

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, command-prompt

I need to install the `pyinstaller` so I go onto my `command prompt` but when I type in :

`pip install pyinstaller`

It prompted this following error:

`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command%2C+operable+program+or+batch+file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question will be `Set up PATH_VARIABLE`  of `pip`.
You get this error is due to the Operating system not recognise the Variable.

Can Learn from here : [HERE](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)